# Creating Google Maps Clusters by type

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I would like to know if it is possible to cluster markets on Google Maps not only by density or number, but also by type.

For example: I have 20 markers of type A and 50 of type B. Could I have a two different clusters, one grouping all the type A markers and another one with type B markers. Obviously with different icons.

Another possible solution would be a single cluster that its icon would change depending of the number of markers of type.

For example: if we have 20 markers type A and 50 type B, the cluster would be a B-Type image.

Any of this options can be possible?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: you can add type A markers to say an object of MarkerClusterer called mcA and type B to mcB.

Comment: Thanks! But if I zoom out, mcA and mcB would cluster togheter?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have a different `MarkerClusterer` for different types of markers. My map has seven different `MarkerClusterer` instances (I actually use: [MarkerClustererPlus](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries#MarkerClustererPlus)) managing different marker types, with different icons as you describe.

You *could* achieve your second option, but it would be some messy code with constant checking, re-checking, and setting of `MarkerClusterer` options. I **strongly** recommend the first option.

Answer (score 0):

hope this may help you-

[Google Maps Server-side Clustering with Asp.net](https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-server-side-clustering-dotnet/)