# MarkerClusterer and the default icons

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I have a map with, say, 3 groups of markers (red, blue and green ones) that represent different kind of stores.

[image]

I need to group that multiple markers into a cluster, like MarkerClusterer does.

But for the moment I don't know if there is some ways to work with heterogeneous types of markers.

Let's say the simplest way is to group all markers regardless of its color when we unzoom. Is that possible to however to set a different color (red, blue and green specific) when the group is zoomed?

Comment: A [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#icons) has an icon, can be whatever you want.  The MarkerClusterer clusters them, when they uncluster, they have their own icons.  That is how it works, you don't need to do anything special. What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Let's say the simplest way is to group all markers regardless of its
>   color when we unzoom. Is that possible to however to set a different
>   color (red, blue and green specific) when the group is zoomed?

Yes, you can freely set the appearance of your markers (they can have different icons) that are clustered by the MarkerClusterer. Then after zoom MarkerClusterer will show your colored markers.

Answer (score 1):

You could create multiple markerClusterer Instances for every type of markers you have and display them all on 1 map, i didn't tried it, but i [read about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669295/creating-google-maps-clusters-by-type).

Just add your makers to one big array

```
var markers = [red, blue, green];
```

Then when you create the markers you add them

```
//Pseudcode
for(every marker with category red)
    markers[red].push(marker);
```

After that you just create the markerclusterers

```
//Pseudocode
for(every category in markers)
    mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers[category], mcOptions);
```

I couldn't test it, but this is the idea and should be working like this.